# Bash: How do I get the wordcount of a file and insert it into the file itself?

Tags: bash

I'm not an experienced bash user. I want to get the word count of a file and insert it back into the file to use as an identifier.

First I initialize the variable `wordcnt` as zero.

```
wordcnt=0;
```

Then I run the code

```
for file in *.txt; do 
wordcnt=$((wc -w < $file));
echo "<field name='wordcount'>$wordcnt</field>" >> $file;
done
```

The result I'm getting is

```
-bash: wc -w < file.txt: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator 
(error token is ".txt")
```

I don't think I can apply the word count to the `wordcnt` variable the way that I'm doing it.

How do I apply the word count to a variable so that I can insert it into the file afterwards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to drop the extra pair of parens:

```
for file in *.txt; do 
    wordcnt=$(wc -w < $file);
    echo "<field name='wordcount'>$wordcnt</field>" >> $file;
done
```

The command substitution `$(..)` will capture the output of `wc` and assign it to the variable `wordcnt`.

Comment: Probably will need remove the unneded spaces from before the number of words. now will get `<field name='wordcount'>     100</field>`

Comment: Thanks for that! It worked! And I did get the extra unnecessary spaces, is there a way to prevent that or is it just the way things are?

Comment: Use `${wordcnt// }` instead of simply `$wordcnt`

Comment: @AnonyMouse I just tried it and I don't get any unnecessary spaces. Tested on `GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0)`.

Comment: I'm on `GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)` and I needed to use `${wordcnt// }`, otherwise there were spaces. Thanks guys! :-)